# Why is $\sum_{s=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{s+1} \left[\vphantom{\Large A}-2^{-s}\ \left(2^s-2\right)\ \zeta\left(s\right)\right]= 1-\log (2)$?

Tags: calculus

could you give and explanation why 
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{s+1}
\left[\vphantom{\Large A}-2^{-s}\ \left(2^s-2\right)\ \zeta\left(s\right)\right]
=
1-\log (2)
$$ 
and $$\sum _{s=0}^{\infty } -2^{-2 s} \left(2^{2 s}-1\right) \zeta (2 s+1)=\frac{1}{4} \left[\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)\vphantom{\LARGE A^{A}}\right]$$ 
i look in a forum and i think it is not convergent.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first formula, and in a similar way the second formula, most likely follows from the alternating zeta function ([Dirichlet Eta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html)):

$$\eta(s):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s),$$

where the second equality is a fun exercise (hint: factor $1/k^s$ whenever it's even). Now, multiply both sides by $(-1)^{s+1}$ and sum both sides in $s$. The r.h.s. is exactly your sum in question, up to a minus sign. The sum in question looks like

$$\sum_{s=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(-1)^{s+1}}{k^s}$$

and as Steven rightfully pointed out, this is not absolutely convergent at $s=1$. However, as Daniel pointed out, the sum can actually be started at $s=2$, since on the r.h.s, $(1-2^{1-s})$ is 0 when $s=1$.  So the sum is really

$$\sum_{s=2}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(-1)^{s+1}}{k^{s}}$$

which now converges absolutely at $s=2$ and onward. So we can swap the double sums, and the important summation is then

$$\sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{s+1}}{k^{s}}=\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^3}-\cdots\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{1+1/k}+1\right)=\left(-\frac{k}{k+1}+1\right)=\frac{1}{k+1},$$

and now,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k+1}=\log(1+1)-1=\log(2)-1$$

since the l.h.s. is the Maclauren series of $\log(1+x)$ with $x=1$.

Comment: I'm a little confused - the absolute value double-sum *doesn't* converge, does it?  After all, the $s=1$ 'row' is the harmonic sum.  Heuristically the argument seems relatively solid but convergence for swapping the sums would seem to need a more delicate touch...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: thanks for the remark, that was dumb on my part. I've tried to salvage this but there's still work to be done. Perhaps someone can comment on a more elegant method.

Comment: Note that effectively the sum starts at $s = 2$, since $2^s-2 = 0$ for $s = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ahhhh! Thanks!

Comment: well done Alex any idea about the second sum?